# How to make one to one (private) chat using Socket.io and MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, chat, p2p, mern

Currently it is sending and receiving a message to every user in the users list. You can see in the image.

How can I send message to particular user and except that user no one else should receive the message? Only selected users can communicate one to one(privately). Is there any problem in the 'showmessagespace' function? Also, for new users I want to open his/her new message space with his/her previous message or blank space and not the common one.

server code :- In server code when I uncomment 'io.to(data.username).emit' it is not sending the message to the receiver, only displaying it on senders tab.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => { /* socket object may be used to send specific messages to the new connected client */
  console.log('connection established',socket.id);
  socket.on('send', (data)=>{
    console.log("Receive data from single username",data)
    console.log('connection established',socket.id);
    console.log(data.username)
    socket.join(data.username)
  });
  socket.on('sended',data=>{
      console.log("gtf")
      // io.to(data.username).emit('sended',data)
      io.emit('sended',data)
  })
  
  socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
    console.log("disconnect")
  })
});
```

React (client) code: When I click on message button of users `showmessagespace` is called but the messages are received by every users in the list and whenever I send msg to particulr user it is sending to every user connected. You can see here when I send a message it is receiving and sending too.

[image]

But when I change user it is still sending msg to sahil and also to abc:

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserService from "../services/userservice";
import {getUsersFriend} from "../services/messageservice";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const SOCKET_IO_URL = "http://localhost:4000";

export default class Messages extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.socket = io(SOCKET_IO_URL)
        this.state = {
            currentUser: UserService.getCurrentUser(),
            isLoading:false,
            userdetails:[],
            show:false,
            username:'',
            message:'',
            senderusername:'',
            socketConnected:false,
            messages:[]
        };
        this.onTextboxChangeMessage = this.onTextboxChangeMessage.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const {currentUser}=this.state
        this.fetchUser()
        this.socket.on('connect',()=> {
            this.setState({ socketConnected : true})
            this.socket.on('sended',(data)=>{ 
                console.log('component did mount',data)
                console.log(this.state.username==data.sendername)
                    console.log(this.state.username,data.username,data.senderusername)
                    this.setState({messages:[...this.state.messages,data]})
                    console.log(this.state.messages)                
            })
        })
        
    }

    async fetchUser(){
        try{
            const {currentUser} = this.state
            console.log(currentUser)
            const data = { userid : currentUser.user._id }
            console.log(data)
            let user = await getUsersFriend(data)
            this.setState({ userdetails: user });
            // console.log(user)
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    showMessageSpace(elementusername){
        this.setState({
            show: true,
            username:elementusername
        });
        console.log(this.socket.id)
    }

    onTextboxChangeMessage(e){
        this.setState({ message:e.target.value})
    }

    SendMessage(username,message,senderusername){
        const {messages} =this.state
        if(this.state.socketConnected){
            console.log('if condition test',username,message,senderusername )
            // this.socket.emit('send',{username,message,senderusername,to:this.socket.id });
            this.socket.emit('send',{username });
            console.log('condition username',`${username}`,  )
            console.log(this.socket.id)
            this.socket.emit('sended',{username,message,senderusername });
        }
        this.setState( { message:'' })
    }

    

    render(){
        const { currentUser ,isLoading,userdetails,message,messages} = this.state;
        console.log(messages)
        if (isLoading) {
            return (<div><p>Loading...</p></div>);
        }

        if(!currentUser){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Redirect  to='/login' />
                </div>
            )
        }
        else{
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Messages</h1>
                <div>
                    <p>Users</p>
                    {' '}
                    <ul className="collection">
                        {userdetails.map((element) => {
                            return(
                                <div key={element._id}>
                                    <li><Link to={`/dashboard/profile/:${element._id}`}>{element.username}</Link>{' '}<input 
                                    type="button" 
                                    id={element._id}
                                    value="Message"
                                    onClick={this.showMessageSpace.bind(this,element.username)} ></input></li>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                        }
                    </ul>
                    {' '}
                </div>
                {' '}
                    <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                {' '}
                <div>
                {
                    this.state.show &&
                    (<div>
                        <h2>Send Message to : {' '}{this.state.username}</h2>
                        {' '}
                        <div className="jumbotron">
                            <h3>Body</h3>
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                {messages.length > 0 && messages.map((msg,key) =>{
                                    return(<li key={key}>{msg.senderusername}<span>{' '}{msg.message}</span></li>);
                                })
                                }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                        <div>
                            {' '}
                            <input 
                            type="text"
                            name="message"
                            value={message}
                            onChange={this.onTextboxChangeMessage}
                            ></input>
                            <button className='btn btn-info' onClick={this.SendMessage.bind(this,this.state.username,this.state.message,currentUser.user.username )}>Send</button>
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                    </div>)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please find your shift key and use proper punctuation. It's difficult to read lower-case sentences all strung together.

Comment: My expirience tell me than its imposible to make full chat app with Reactjs && Socket.io,we can make public chat or private chat,both in one,no chance.I made full chat app with jQuery && socket.io but with reactjs,i cant,i gave my best and i failed.

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke could you send link of how you made chatapp

Comment: How is too huge question,you can see here -> https://stark-hamlet-40961.herokuapp.com/